# What is the correct way to say "-shaped"?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

How do you correctly say "sth-shaped", such as "heart-shaped" or "star-shaped"? Do you say 心状？星星状？

Comment: http://www.iciba.com/-shaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shape (n): 形狀

to shape (v): 塑造

shaped (adj): 形状的

- *you can omit 状 in  形状的*

Example:

heart-**shaped**= 心**形的**

star-**shaped** = 星星**形的**

Comment: Note that 星形 is also fine.